# Bitcoin node generating invalid addresses

Tags: wallet, nodes

I'm running both a bitcoin and a litecoin node, both are generating invalid addresses.

My LTC generated address:
**MV6eGvkbkgcDZLDpK1WQeZLMmx3PHZmXC7**

My BTC generated address:
**2MvuZyhhGHCUcFPHCEUNeBbGEKYJ5wpytjk**

I'm generating them in the bitcoin-cli/litecoin-cli with getnewaddress

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Those look like valid P2SH testnet addresses. Is that not what you expected?

Comment: not really, the node is pointing to the main net, what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have -testnet or -regtest on the command line? Or in bitcoin.conf?

Comment: What does `getbestblockhash` print out?

Comment: it gets the last block: 85c058d5541a7eafdb159ebb9f00be39dbfd17a41fed5d33104c075afeebef9f

Comment: no -testnet or -regtest on command line or bitcoin.conf

Comment: MV63... appears to be a valid P2SH Litecoin address and contains LTC 0.19 according to https://chainz.cryptoid.info/ltc/address.dws?MV6eGvkbkgcDZLDpK1WQeZLMmx3PHZmXC7.htm.  So everything may be correct on the Litecoin side.  The Bitcoin one really does look like testnet; what does `getbestblockhash` print out there?

Comment: 2MVu... is a valid P2SH testnet address, anyway; I just sent some coins to it :-) https://www.blocktrail.com/tBTC/address/2MvuZyhhGHCUcFPHCEUNeBbGEKYJ5wpytjk